# Keyrock Installation

Tags: fiware

I was following the manual installation steps provided here:

[https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Identity_Management_-*KeyRock*-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Identity_Management_-_KeyRock_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide)

We do not know what to do in the step "4. Initial Sample Data" of keystone, since it says that we should use the automatic installation tools if we plan to use keystone with Fiware Identity Management. Then, Can we install Keyrock manually? or we have to do it through the automatic tools in order to use keystone with Fiware.

Thanks in advance,
Rafa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to give you an answer with out knowing your specific use case so I will try to give a broad explanation.

Yes, you can install it manually if that's what you want. The "Initial Sample Data" step depends on how do you want to use the Identity Manager (or its back-end part based on Keystone). The sample data is simply some fake data in the database so you can right away demo or test the Identity Manager. That said, the installation instructions are not very clear in explaining that there is some "required data" and some "testing data", so I will try to explain it better here (and update the wiki afterwards :) )

If you ONLY want our modified version of Keystone (you plan to use it as the Keystone component of an OpenStack deployment) you don't need to bother with this "sample data" at all. You will need to create users for the services, roles, projects, services, endpoints etc. as a normal Keystone installation. For creating all of this you have three options: create it by hand, use the sample_data.sh script provided by Keystone (as hinted in the wiki) as a starting point or use the keystone.populate in the automated tools (which you can modify to suit your needs).

If you plan to use the whole Identity Manager component (Keystone back-end + Horizon front-end) then you still need this "required data" but the Keystone provided sample_data.sh is not anymore a valid starting point, you should do it either by hand or using keystone.populate. Additionally, you can create some "sample data" to test out the IdM right away with some users, organizations and applications. You can create this either by hand or using the automated tools' task keystone.test_data.

I will rewrite that section on the wiki to better reflect this options and to also add a list with all the "required data" for each situation. Hopefully this answer wasn't too confusing.

Comment: ok, I used the automatic tools in order to install Keyrock since I want to use keystone and horizon.

I think it would be useful to clarify this in the installation guide.

Now we have errors when trying to configure a pep proxy wilma with this local keyrock instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178399/configuration-wilma-pep-proxy-4-3-keyrock-4-3-local-instance-idas